# Dataflow pipeline is dropping events during processing when using outputWithTimestamp

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Cloud Dataflow pipeline in which I alter the original timestamp for the event in order to simulate real world scenarios of events arriving late. However, it appears I'm dropping some percentage of my events on each run of the pipeline. Inside my DoFn I use the following code to change the timestamp:

```
Instant newTimestamp = originalTimestamp.minus(Duration.standardMinutes(RANDOM.nextInt(15)));
c.outputWithTimestamp(KV.of(Integer.toString(RANDOM.nextInt(100)), element), newTimestamp);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most likely caused by your DoFn step outputting a timestamp that is earlier than the timestamp that was received by the processing step minus the allowed timestamp skew. The exception that would be thrown can be found here in the code:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/util/DoFnRunnerBase.java#L493

This behavior is documented with regard to using outputWithTimestamp here:

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/DoFn.Context#outputWithTimestamp-OutputT-org.joda.time.Instant-

While you could override the getAllowedTimestampSkew function, is is also documented that this might cause unpredictable issues with the watermark calculations so it should only be used without windowing/grouping.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/DoFn#getAllowedTimestampSkew--